# Can there be an Irrational Numbers Hotel?

Tags: intuition, irrational-numbers, infinity

I am not a mathematician. However, I have been impressed by what I have read about Hilbert and his famous hotel. But, while I can see that all kinds of number series to infinity are possible.  I wondered whether the Irrational Room Number Hotel could exist.  My (inexpert) question relates to irrational numbers, which seem to exist.  Yet how could you have a key with such a number on it, that, even if you could fit it in your pocket because of its infinitesimal writing, no guest could possibly read it?

I am sorry to be asking such a naïve question, but an explanation of my lack of understanding might help me understand Hilbert and infinite numbers a bit better.

Comment: I am not very familiar with that problem , but i think you should keep in mind that the rationals are countable and the irrationals aren't.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) or [definable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number).  Just because there are only countably many computable numbers however is not disproof of the existence of the rest of the irrational numbers.  Also, just because a perfect analogy to a real world scenario doesn't exist for the real numbers as a whole is also not justification to discredit the usefulness or theory surrounding the uncomputable numbers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remember that Hilbert's Hotel is just a tool to illustrate some of the oddities of infinity.  No one has built it yet and maybe they never will.  We don't yet know whether the universe is finite or infinite.

You might be able to play some games with an irrational numbers hotel but, for the reasons that Steve explains, forget about the problem with the keys for the moment.

Suppose that Hilbert has completed his hotel based on the natural numbers $\{1, 2, 3, . . .\}$.  Its logo is $\mathbb{N}$.  It is successful and he wants to expand.  He adds a room $0$ and lets it out.  He then realizes that he has wasted his time.  Even when the expanded hotel is full, he can ask everyone to move up a room.  Everyone gets a new room yet the new room $0$ is free.  It wasn't needed.

Next, he is more ambitious and extends in the opposite direction with rooms labelled by the negative numbers $\{-1, -2, -3, . . .\}$ and now has his Integer Hotel. He gives it the logo $\mathbb{Z}$.  However, he finds that again he has wasted his time.  He can move all of the guests from the expanded hotel to the original hotel and again everyone gets a room and the new negative rooms were not needed. The relocation formula is a bit more complicated but the keys can be remotely programmed to show the new room number. A voucher for a free drink in the bar resolves the customer complaints

Now, he tries to build an infinite set of hotels: a whole copy of his original hotel for each natural number. The keys now show two numbers e.g. hotel $73$ room $257$.  He uses the logo $\mathbb{N}^2$ for the chain. Yet again, he is disappointed and even when all of the hotels in the new chain are full, he can still relocate them back to his original hotel. This time, the customers are more upset at the disruption and he needs to offer a voucher for a free meal in the restaurant to calm them down.

He briefly considers Rational Hotel with the logo $\mathbb{Q}$ but he realizes that it is a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$.  He considers Algebraic Hotel with logo $\mathbb{A}$ and room numbers such as $\sqrt 2$ and $\varphi$ (The Golden Ratio room which is popular with honeymooners.)  Yet again, he realizes that he is wasting his time.

He then succumbs to depression for many years. There seems to be no way to expand his business.  Eventually, he comes across [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) and he figures out how he can expand.  He builds Hilbert's Real Hotel with logo $\mathbb{R}$ and finds that it is really bigger. When it is full, the guests cannot all be moved back to the original hotel without someone being left out in the street.  The new hotel is a roaring success, the transcendental rooms are especially popular and, better still, there are plenty of them: more than the boring rational and algebraic rooms.

He briefly considers Hibert's Complex Hotel with logo $\mathbb{C}$ but realizes that is not any bigger than his Real Hotel.  Anyway, some of the rooms are imaginary.

Again, the business stagnates for a while until he rebrands the Real Hotel as **Hotel Beth 1** with logo $\beth_1$ and follows up with $\beth_2$ and $\beth_3$.  He can continue to grow his business for ever.  See [Beth number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) for more details of his plans.

An additional chapter of the story suggested by Vsotvep's comment.

Cantor goes into competition with Hilbert and builds his **Hotel Aleph $0$** with logo $\aleph_0$.  Hilbert accepts that it is just as big as his original hotel.  Thanks to a generous promotional offer (free use of the club lounge) all of the guests switch from Hilbert's Natural Hotel to the new one.

Things get more complex when Cantor expands to his **Hotel Aleph $1$** $\aleph_1$.  Some people think that it as big as **Hilbert's Hotel Beth $1$**.  Some think that it isn't.  Most just don't know.  The hotel critics Cohen and Gödel claim that it can't be known.  The dispute becomes known as [The Continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Things just get worse with Cantor's $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3$ hotels.  The dispute becomes known as [The Generalized Continuum Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis)

Disclaimer [None of the hotels in this story are based on real hotels whether past, present, or future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer).

Comment: This is gold! (+1)

Comment: His real headache started when he tried to create a medium-sized hotel; something larger than his Integer Hotel, yet not as large as the Real Hotel. It gave him such a headache, that it has become known in the hotel business as the [first of Hilbert's problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: @Vsotvep Thanks. You inspired me to write another chapter of the story.

Comment: Banach and Tarski got contract to build Real Hotel in his back yard. Cool round design included.

Comment: Thank for this response.  My background is philosophy and logic.  What I wonder, is whether the underling issue lies in the fact that our numbers are a kind of language game whose rules (addition, subtraction) set no limit on the results.  The rules of GO are like this.  There is no limit set to the number of squares or of stones.  Our rules, for example, permit negative numbers. But so far, at least one boundary has been found: absolute zero.  The other negatives seem to follow from some human and so artificial zero boundary.  In the other direction the rules for number allow no limit.

Comment: @Tuffy Thanks.  I enjoyed writing it.  It is a very strange area of mathematics.  Have you read Roger Penrose's Road to Reality?  https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=roger+penrose+the+road+to+reality&adgrpid=53890692940&gclid=CjwKCAiAhc7yBRAdEiwAplGxX8cGmjwkYcJ60_-ZuI22Z2bXIq7s4CrtBlSU4rGwnvtnE5zdABZrzBoCusAQAvD_BwE&hvadid=259122716805&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1007130&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=2676826228959292312&hvtargid=aud-857384558300%3Akwd-301632342423&hydadcr=11496_1841783&tag=googhydr-21&ref=pd_sl_5plpdax9u_e It is popular maths but not dumbed down.

Comment: @Tuffy In that book Penrose mentions that a lot of maths has proved useful in physics even if it initially seemed to be totally abstract and useless e.g. complex numbers.  He seems surprised that the theory of infinite numbers has not yet proved useful.

Comment: @badjohn No, but I admire him enormously.  I have STRUGGLED through his Fashion, Faith and Fantasy, with equal pleasure and incomprehension!  I need to study maths properly.

Comment: @talex It is tempting to add another chapter.  Banach and Tarski attempt to duplicate the Real Hotel without using any more material.  A very sneaky plan: they buy only one set of materials but can sell the result twice (or many times).  The plan fails as they are unable to measure the cuts accurately enough.

Comment: @TuffyThe book may suit you.  Some popular maths books are very dumbed down (necessarily) but this one is not.  You can really learn from it.  Some chapters may be  tough but many are independent so you can skip ones that you cannot follow or don't enjoy.

Comment: @Continuum Hypothesis  I really appreciated your answer. I think I have found a better way to ask it now.  If I have booked a room in the irrational numbers hotel, how could I know whether the room I think it is to a million decimal places will turn out to be the right room a few decimal places later?  If a number is irrational, then how could I know?  Or is it just that I could simply revert to fractions and abandon decimalisation?

Answer (score 1):

There is only a countable number of different finite-length labels (room numbers) that could be written on a key with a finite or countable set of symbols (such as digits or letters), so I don't think you could have a labeled key for each room unless the labels could be infinite. However, you can certainly print some irrational room numbers on keys (such as $\pi$), just not all of them, notwithstanding the impossibility of having even countably infinitely many keys in one universe.

Comment: Well, even the usual Hilbert's Hotel is tricky to build.