# Conjecture about rational numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, irrational-numbers, conjectures, normal-number

Inspired by [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) I created the simple following problem:

First take a rational number, for example $\frac{3}{4}$ which is equal to $0.75$; now add the first digit after the decimal separator to the digit $4$ we get $\frac{3}{4.7}$ which is equal $0.63829\cdots$. Now take the second digit after the dot of the new number $0.63829\cdots$ and add it to the number $4.7$ we get  $\frac{3}{4.73}$. We can repeat the process an infinity of times.

Now, I conjecture that if we make the process on the numerator there exists a period of digits which is repeated infinitely many times i.e it's a rational number.We have diffrerent category of number.Well take $\frac{5}{4}$ and we recognize something like a divisibility .There is an other example wich is a counter-example I think it's $\frac{729}{653}$ it's a special example because the digit after the dot of the numerator corresponds to the digits after the dot of the result .Well furthermore $653$ is a prime number so maybe we can find a criteria to distinguish rational and irrational number (always with numerator) with the prime number.  On the other hand as in my example I conjecture that it's not the case for the denominator i.e it's a irrational number. I have tested all the rational numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ such that $0<a\leq b\leq 100$ for my second conjecture.

To prove it I have tried to build something similar to the following paper (without success) https://www.claymath.org/library/annual_report/ar2006/06report_normalnumbers.pdf

My question :

Can we find a criteria or a method to know if we have a rational or a irrational number making the process describe above ?

I think this is the kind of problem which is either trivial, either not for this century (remember a quote of Paul Erdös).

Update :

Well making a Google research I found this [Can there be an Irrational Numbers Hotel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557700/can-there-be-an-irrational-numbers-hotel)  .In fact my little algorithm is not new see the Cantor's diagonal argument .So I'm a little bit sad .Moreover I think there is a link with  prime gaps .good day :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated...

...Thanks a lot for all your contributions.

Comment: There seems to be an interesting question here, but your post needs some serious clean up. I won't vote to close as I think your question is an interesting one, but please take some time to fix your post. Please consider rewriting it in more clear and formal English, remove the unnecessary and boisterous comments near the end, and perhaps explain in more detail what you are considering

Comment: "there exists a period of digits which is repeated infinitely many times". What do you mean more precisely please? Do you mean something like $0.251919191919...$ (which is rational, equal to $2494/9900$), or do you also allow for more complicated cases?

Comment: Interesting idea (+1) , my first impression is that a proof or disproof is out of reach. But I admit , I just have seen the question, so this conclusion can be too fast.

Comment: Thanks for all your comment I have not really the time today but let me the some days to think about this .